# Combinatorica - binary order

Tags: combinatorics

i tried to solve this question without success.
do anyone know the answer?

f(n,m) presents the number of binary strings (empty string included) that include at most n-1 times '1', and at most m times '0'.

prove:
f(n,m) = $\binom{n+m+2}{n+1}-1$

Comment: You have asked this question three times - please do not do that. At the same time, when you ask a question please include additional context: where did you encounter the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty inductive work.

First check the equation for $m=0$ - it should give $f(n,0)=n$, because there are $n-1$ strings which contain exactly $1, 2, ... n-1$ ones, plus one empty string.

Then check for adding zeros - you should get $f(n,m+1) = f(n,m) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)$, because for string with $i$ ones there are $i+1$ distinct places, where a zero can be added (these are: before any '1', after the first '1', after the second '1', ... and after the $i$-th '1') and $f(n,m)$ counts strings with zero to $n-1$ '1'.